# How to put information into prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, weblogic-10.x

```
> The father sat to the right of the person who had corn, 
> who sat to the right of the person who ate pork, who sat to the right of the
> person who had baked potato, who sat to the right of the person who
> had peas.
```

How this can be converted into Prolog predicates? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first rephrase this as "right to the person who had corn is the father. right to the person who ate pork is the person who had corn." etc. And then use the predicate right(x, y) for "right to x is y". The end result is:

```
right(corn, father).
right(pork, corn).
right(potato, pork).
right(peas, potato).
```

Comment: This answer is not satisfactory. You can infer nothing more than the mere facts stated from this theory while from the specification you'd be able to infer much more.